# why doesn't this go code print anything with a goroutine

Tags: go

I must be missing something really basic about goroutines, but I've looked around and I cannot see any reason why this would not work...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        //fmt.Println(i)
        go func(j int) {
            fmt.Println(j + 100)
        }(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is finishing before your goroutines have a chance to run.

Here's your code with a [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(j int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(j + 100)
        }(i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Waiting...")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lmCPU9-qkB

Answer (score 1):

[From the spec of Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It **does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines** to
>   complete.

See Jack's answer for a working version.